# jenkins groovy shell curl command not working

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

While running the curl command using sh in Jenkins pipeline, the curl GET request after "&" is not getting sent.

```
pipeline{
  agent{
      node{
          label 'xxxx'
      }
  }
  stages{
    stage('first'){
      steps{
        script{
          def url = 'xxxxx/sonar/api/qualitygates'
          def project = 'xxxx'
          def pr = 'xxx'
          sh "curl -u xxxx: ${url}/project_status?projectKey=${project}&branch=${pr}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Somehow the "&" and anything after that is not read during command execution.

Console output in Jenkins

```
+ branch=xxxx
+ curl -u xxxx: 'xxxxxx/sonar/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=xxxxx'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

Comment: Your last comamd after "&" do nothing? It's just branch=${pr}. So no output will be displayed

Comment: Add additional double quotes around the url or escape the & with \&

Comment: Thanks this worked,  ```sh "curl -u xxxx: "+url+"/project_status?projectKey=${project}\"&branch=\"${pr}"```

Answer (score 0):

for & in URL you should add \ for that
like this: "curl URL/param1=value1&param2=value2"